# Nginx - reverse proxy pass packets to localhost

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Say for example I have nginx proxy setup like such:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  foo.com;
    #SSL and logging settings omitted

    location /datapath1 {
        proxy_read_timeout      3500;
        proxy_connect_timeout   3250;

        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:12345/;
    }

    location /datapath2 {
        proxy_read_timeout      3500;
        proxy_connect_timeout   3250;

        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass              http://localhost:23456/;
    }
}
```

The idea is that when this server receives POST requests to different data paths, the packets will be decrypted and sent to programs that run on the same machine, and response will be generated by the programs then encrypted and sent back to clients by nginx.

I know I can send HTTPS packets directly to the ports the programs are listening to...but I like this approach better because it hides the ports, and I do not need to mess around with caching and SSL in the programs, just let nginx handle them. Plus I more or less have to use a proxy server anyway...so I want to explore the possibility.

Will this work at all?

Comment: How exactly could unencrypted packets possibly be exposed to another machine?

Comment: I assume it is impossible, but I am not sure so that is why I am asking :) Just want to make sure. @MichaelHampton

Comment: Take a moment to understand [what localhost means](http://serverfault.com/a/502721/126632).

Comment: OK thanks Michael, now I need to edit the question to ask the nginx stuff @MichaelHampton

Comment: Yes this is a widely used [feature](http://wiki.nginx.org/SSL-Offloader) of nginx.